# C find elapsed time in C Linux

Tags: c, performance

I have to calculate the time taken by a function to complete.
This function is called in a loop and I want to find out the total time.
Usually the time is very less in either nano or micro seconds.

To find out the elapsed time I used functions gettimeofday() using struct timeval and clock_gettime() using struct  timespec.

Problem is time return by timeval in seconds is correct but in micro seconds wrong.
Similarly the time returned by timespec in nano seconds is wrong.
Wrong in the sense they do not tally with the time returned in seconds.

For clock_gettime() I tried both CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID and CLOCK_MONOTONIC.
Using clock() also does not help.

Code snippet:

```
struct timeval funcTimestart_timeval, funcTimeEnd_timeval;
struct timespec funcTimeStart_timespec, funcTimeEnd_timespec;

unsigned long elapsed_nanos = 0;
unsigned long elapsed_seconds = 0;
unsigned long diffInNanos = 0;

unsigned long Func_elapsed_nanos = 0;
unsigned long Func_elapsed_seconds = 0;

while(...)
{
   gettimeofday(&funcTimestart_timeval, NULL);
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &funcTimeStart_timespec);
   ...
   demo_func();
   ...
   gettimeofday(&funcTimeEnd_timeval, NULL);
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &funcTimeEnd_timespec);

   elapsed_seconds = funcTimeEnd_timeval.tv_sec - funcTimestart_timeval.tv_sec;
   Func_elapsed_seconds+= elapsed_seconds;

   elapsed_nanos = funcTimeEnd_timespec.tv_nsec - funcTimeStart_timespec.tv_nsec;
   Func_elapsed_nanos+ = elapsed_nanos;
}

printf("Total time taken by demo_func() is %lu seconds( %lu nanoseconds )\n", Func_elapsed_seconds, Func_elapsed_nanos );
```

Printf output:

```
Total time taken by demo_func() is 60 seconds( 76806787 nanoseconds )
```

See that the time in seconds and nanoseconds do not match.

How to resolve this issue or any other appropriate method to find elapsed time?

Answer (score 5):

Did you read the documentation of [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)? Please read it twice.

The `struct timespec` is not supposed to express *twice* the same time. The field `tv_sec` gives the second part *ts*, and the field `tv_nsec` gives the nanosecond part *tn* to express the 
 time *t = ts + 10<sup>-9</sup> tn*

I would suggest to convert that to a floating point, e.g.

```
printf ("total time %g\n",
        (double)Func_elapsed_seconds + 1.0e-9*Func_elapsed_nanos);
```

Using floating point is simpler and generally the precision is enough for most needs. Otherwise, when you add or substract `struct timespec` you need to handle the case when the added/substracted `tv_nsec` field sum/difference is negative or more than 1000000000....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are printing/comparing wrong values.

`76,806,787 nanoseconds` is equal to `~76 milliseconds`, you cannot compare it with 60 seconds.

You are ignoring the time in seconds stored in `funcTimeEnd_timespec.tv_sec`.

You should also print `funcTimeEnd_timespec.tv_sec - funcTimeStart_timespec.tv_sec`, and as *@Basile Starynkevitch* suggested, add with it the nanoseconds part after multiplying it with `10e-9`. Then you can compare time elapsed shown by both functions.

Comment: I am replying to the comment as answer as I wanted to paste code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I am replying to the previous answers as answer as I wanted to paste code snippets.

Question is to find out elapsed time whether
first I should subtract the corresponding times with each other and then add

```
(end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + 1.0e-9*(end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)
```

or
first add the times and then compute the difference

```
(end.tv_sec + 1.0e-9*end.tv_nsec) - (start.tv_sec + 1.0e-9*start.tv_nsec)
```

In the first case quite often end.tv_nsec is less in number then start.tv_nsec and hence the difference becomes negative number nd this give me wrong number.